# Build multiple docker images without building binaries in each Dockerfile

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, azure-devops, dotnet-cli

I have a .NET Core solution with 6 runnable applications (APIs) and multiple netstandard projects. In a build pipeline on Azure DevOps I need to create 6 Docker images and push them to the Azure Registry.

Right now what I do is I build image by image and every one of these 6 Dockerfiles builds the solution from scratch (restores, builds, publishes). This takes a few minutes and the whole pipeline goes almost to 30 minutes.

My goal is to optimize the time of the build. I figured two possible, parallel, ways of doing that:

- remove restore and build, run just publish (because it restores references and does the same thing as build)
- publish the code once (for all runnable applications) and in Dockerfiles just copy binaries, without building again

Are both ways doable? I can't figure out how to make the second one work - should I just run `dotnet publish` for each runnable application and then gather all Dockerfiles within the folder with binaries and run `docker build`? My concern is - I will need to copy required .dll files to the image but how do I choose which ones, without explicitly specifying them?

**EDIT:**

I'm using Linux containers. I don't write my Dockerfiles - they are autogenerated by Visual Studio. I'll show you one example:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Application.WebAPI/Application.WebAPI.csproj", "Application.WebAPI/"]
COPY ["Processing.Dependency/Processing.Dependency.csproj", "Processing.Dependency/"]
COPY ["Processing.QueryHandling/Processing.QueryHandling.csproj", "Processing.QueryHandling/"]
COPY ["Model.ViewModels/Model.ViewModels.csproj", "Model.ViewModels/"]
COPY ["Core.Infrastructure/Core.Infrastructure.csproj", "Core.Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["Model.Values/Model.Values.csproj", "Model.Values/"]
COPY ["Sql.Business/Sql.Business.csproj", "Sql.Business/"]
COPY ["Model.Events/Model.Events.csproj", "Model.Events/"]
COPY ["Model.Messages/Model.Messages.csproj", "Model.Messages/"]
COPY ["Model.Commands/Model.Commands.csproj", "Model.Commands/"]
COPY ["Sql.Common/Sql.Common.csproj", "Sql.Common/"]
COPY ["Model.Business/Model.Business.csproj", "Model.Business/"]
COPY ["Processing.MessageBus/Processing.MessageBus.csproj", "Processing.MessageBus/"]
COPY ["Processing.CommandHandling/Processing.CommandHandling.csproj", "Processing.CommandHandling/"]
COPY ["Processing.EventHandling/Processing.EventHandling.csproj", "Processing.EventHandling/"]
COPY ["Sql.System/Sql.System.csproj", "Sql.System/"]
COPY ["Application.Common/Application.Common.csproj", "Application.Common/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Application.WebAPI/Application.WebAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Application.WebAPI"
RUN dotnet build "Application.WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Application.WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Application.WebApi.dll"]
```

One more thing - The problem is that azure devops has this job which builds an image and I just copied this job 6 times, pointing every copy to other Dockerfile. That's why they don't reuse the code - I would love to change that so they base on the same binaries. Here are steps in Azure DevOps:

1. Get sources
2. Build and push image no. 1
3. Build and push image no. 2
4. Build and push image no. 3
5. Build and push image no. 4
6. Build and push image no. 5
7. Build and push image no. 6

Every single 'Build and push image' does:

1. dotnet restore
2. dotnet build
3. dotnet publish

I want to get rid of this overhead - is it possible?

Comment: Have you looked at https://andrewlock.net/caching-docker-layers-on-serverless-build-hosts-with-multi-stage-builds---target,-and---cache-from/ ?

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this scenario? I have a very similar problem.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I did not due to the fact that this would take some additional time we did not have at the time.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your Dockerfiles, but you probably are making some mistakes that are adding time to the image build. For example, each command in a Dockerfile results in a layer. Docker caches these layers and only rebuilds the layer if it or previous layers have changed.

A very common mistake people make is to copy their entire project with all the files within *first*, and then run `dotnet restore`. When you do that, any change to any file invalidates that copy layer and thus also the `dotnet restore` layer, meaning that you have to restore packages every single build. The only thing necessary for the `dotnet restore` is the project file(s), so if you copy just those, run `dotnet restore`, and then copy all the files, those layers will be cached, unless the project file itself changes. Since that normally only happens when you change packages (add, update, remove, etc.), most of the time, you will not have to repeat the restore step, and the build will go much quicker.

Another issue can occur when you're using npm and Linux images on Windows. This one bit me personally. In order to support Linux images, Docker uses a Linux VM (MobyLinux). At the start of a build, Docker lifts the entire filesystem context (i.e. where you run the `docker` command) into the MobyLinux VM, first, as all the Dockerfile commands will be run actually in the VM, and thus the files will need to reside there. If you have a `node_modules` directory, it can take a *significant* amount of time to move all that over. You can solve this by adding `node_modules` to your `.dockerignore` file.

There's other similar types of mistakes you might be making. We'd really need to see your Dockerfiles to help you further. Regardless, you should not go with either of your proposed approaches. Just running `publish` will suffer from the same issues described above, and gives you no recourse to alleviate the problem at that point. Publishing outside of the image can lead to platform inconsistencies and other problems unless you're very careful. It also adds a bunch of manual steps to the image building process, which defeats a lot of the benefit Docker provides. Your images will be larger as well, unless you just happen to publish on exactly the same architecture as what the image will use. If you're developing on Windows, but using Linux images, for example, you'll have to include the full ASP.NET Core runtime. If you build and publish within the image, you can include the SDK only in a stage to build and publish, and then target something like alpine linux, with a self-contained architecture-specific publish.

Comment: Please check my edited post. Just wanna add - I'm not a Docker newbie, maybe not an expert but I know my way around so I'm familiar with layers and so on, no need for explaining stuff very deeply :)